I can't get token file to be ignored by git
I accidentally added my token file(tokens/webhook.token) to my first git commit and now i can't get .gitignore to ignore it.
I have tried git rm --cached tokens/webhook.token but it keeps wanting too retrack the file when i then update the webhook token. How do i fix this?
My .gitignore:
# ignore files used for vs code configuration
/.emmyrc.json

# ignore tokens this time
tokens
tokens/webhook.token

# ignore files containing data
database/data.lon
completion/username/players.lon

# ignore temporary files
.autosave.sdoc
.temp.*

# ignore settings
.settings

the github repo: https://github.com/hooded-person/KGinfractions

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+sensitive+file+history
